# ansible gcp_compute_instance - attach existing external ip address when creating vm instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, devops

I want to attach an existing (created before) external ip address when creating vm instance:

- create address

```
- name: create address
  gcp_compute_address:
    name: my-external-ip
    region: europe-west1
    address_type: '{{ item.compute_address_type | default("EXTERNAL") }}'
    network_tier: "{{ item.compute_address_network_tier | default("PREMIUM") }}"
    project: "{{ gcp.project_id }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "{{ gcp.credentials_file }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ compute_address }}"
  register: address
  tags: create_address
```

- create instance

```
- name: create compute instances
  gcp_compute_instance:
    name: my-instance
    zone: europe-west1-b
    machine_type: "{{ item.instance_type }}"
    metadata: "{{ item.instance_metadata | default(omit) }}"
    labels: "{{ item.instance_label | default(omit) }}"
    tags: "{{ item.instance_tags | default(omit) }}"
    scopes: '{{ item.instance_scopes | default("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform") }}'
    disks: "{{ item.disks }}"
    network_interfaces: "{{ item.network_interfaces }}"
    project: "{{ gcp.project_id }}"
    auth_kind: serviceaccount
    service_account_file: "{{ gcp.credentials_file }}"
    state: present
  with_items: "{{ instances }}"
  register: instance
  tags:
 - create_instance
```

- vars for network_interfaces

```
instances:
  network_interfaces:
 - network:
      name: default
    access_configs:
    - name: External NAT
      nat_ip:
        address: projects/project_id/regions/europe-west1/addresses/my-external-ip
      type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
```

- The address has been created:

```
$ gcloud compute addresses describe my-external-ip --region europe-west1
address: 35.X.Y.Z
addressType: EXTERNAL
creationTimestamp: '2020-07-24T03:10:44.048-07:00'
description: ''
id: '1804649404875345227'
kind: compute#address
name: my-external-ip
networkTier: PREMIUM
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project_id/regions/europe-west1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project_id/regions/europe-west1/addresses/my-external-ip
status: RESERVED
```

**Then I run, there's an error:**

```
'message': "Invalid value for field 'resource.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP':
'projects/neoevolution/regions/europe-west1/addresses/neoevolution-dev-eip-1'. 
The specified external IP address 
'projects/neoevolution/regions/europe-west1/addresses/neoevolution-dev-eip-1' 
was not found in region 'europe-west1'
```

**THANKS FOR YOUR HELP, PEACE.**

Comment: when using "selfLink" instead of "address", module create a new ephemeral IP and don't take existing IP address mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Check if your external reserved IP looks good(belong the correct region etc.):

```
gcloud compute addresses list
NAME            ADDRESS/RANGE   TYPE      PURPOSE  NETWORK  REGION        SUBNET  STATUS
my-external-ip  35.207.102.185  EXTERNAL                    europe-west3          RESERVED
```

Try to reference the IP by the address itself rather than the name. I reproduced in a simple deployment and this worked for me:

```
"accessConfigs": [
        {
          "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
          "name": "External NAT",
          "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
          "natIP": "35.207.102.185",
          "networkTier": "STANDARD"
        }
      ]
```

And of course make sure you are referencing your network variables correctly. You may try to hard-code the values to narrow down the possible source of the problem.

Peace! ;)

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried with hard-code value of the network address: 35.X.Y.Z and WORKS FINE. BUT in an automated process, I couldn't know what will be the value of this EIP because all playbook will be ran one after one and all variables must be fixed before running

Comment: Just replace the actual IP address with the name of the reserved IP `my-external-ip` in your yaml. I tested from CLI and it worked on my side: `--address=my-external-ip` assigned the IP address that I have reserved prior to the instance deploy. Please let me know if it worked. I'll update the answer if true. Thanks!

Comment: If that still does not work, you may try to use `$(ref.RESOURCE_NAME.PROPERTY)`. Something like `$(ref.my-external-ip.address)`, but I am not sure if the address can be calculated ahead of time. Sources: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/gcp_compute_address_module.html and https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/use-references

Comment: replaced **address: 35.X.Y.Z** (who worked) by **address: my-external-ip** but not working -- same error:
`The specified external IP address my-external-ip was not found in region europe-west1` --
**my-external-ip** was created in region `europe-west1` --
and EIP is calculated by gcp when it's creating so I wonder if there's a way to get it ahead of time.

Comment: That's strange - if the IP appears to exist in the correct region, it does not make a lot of sense to receive that error message.  Are you deleting the reserved IP between your attempts? Do you reserve the EIP in the same deployment file as the instance deployment? Perhaps the instance deployment is happening just a little bit too fast, before the creation of the EIP. Try to add a depends on statement to force the instance wait for the EIP to be reserved. Here's an example: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-explicit-dependencies

Comment: It seems like you didn't reserve the IP address as regional IP address. You can find more information on the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static)